# Способы оптимизации приложения под экран 3.5''

Tags: оптимизация, objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

По неопытности разработал приложение которое корректно отображается только на 4-дюймовых айфонах(5-5s-5c). Без storyboard's

Как оптимизировать приложение, чтобы нормально показывалось и на айфоне 4.
Желательно, без использования Autolayout'ов.

Создавать отдельные .xib-файлы для айфона4/4с?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучший вариант отдельные xib'ы, Но придется обвесить все контроллеры if'чиками с запросами высоты экрана подобное ниже:

```
 #define ASSET_BY_SCREEN_HEIGHT(regular) (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 480.0) ? regular : [regular stringByAppendingString:@"~568h"])
 [UIImage imageNamed:ASSET_BY_SCREEN_HEIGHT(@"BackgroundAuth")];
```

А чтоб сильно не потеть и раз уж Вы не хотите использовать автолайауты, то при их отключении включаются AutorresizeMask режим.  Он все поджимает, как считает нужным, основываясь на  ваши правила ресайза.

Но мой совет изучить автолайауты и верстать ими. Так как они удовлетворяют всем параметрам.